# How to make the Swiper.js and React Player carousel responsive

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api, carousel, swiper.js, react-player

I have been looking for a way to make my `Swiper.js` carousel responsive when it's nesting the Youtube `React Player`. I finally found a workaround and hope this helps somebody. This also works if the `slidesPerView` is more than 2 or even float number like `slidesPerView={1.3}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default css `mySwiper` class, and apply `player-wrapper` and `react-player` css as below.
The point is that the `player-wrapper` div is self close and does not wrap the `<ReactPlayer>` component. Also have the `width` and `height` props to be `100%` in the `<ReactPlayer>` component.

```
 <Swiper
   slidesPerView={1.3}
   grabCursor={false}
   loop={false}
   watchSlidesProgress={true}
   centeredSlides={true}
   modules={[Pagination, Navigation]}
   // className='mySwiper' <=remove
        >
 <SwiperSlide>
     <div className='player-wrapper' /> //<= self close div
        <ReactPlayer
           url='youtube.com/1234'
           controls={true}
           width='100%'
           height='100%'
           playing={isPlaying === data.id}
           config={{
              youtube: {
              playerVars: { showinfo: 1 },
                        },
                   }}
           className='react-player'
        />
 </SwiperSlide>
```

CSS

```
.player-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%
}
.react-player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```